# Google OAuth2 with SMTP in python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, smtplib

This is code to get creds:

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'myJsonFile.json'
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,)

creds_with_scope = credentials.with_scopes(scopes=scopes)


if creds_with_scope.token == None or creds_with_scope.valid == False:
    creds_with_scope.refresh(Request())
```

Using this code I get a valid Token. But when I try to login to SMTP server with this creds in the code:

```
with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as server:
    
    server.starttls()
    
    server.login(sender_email, creds)
    
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, email_text)
    
    server.quit()
```

I get an error:

```
(535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f26-20020a7bc8da000000b0041076151a8csm579297wml.14 - gsmtp')
```

I than tried to apply only Token attribute such as:

```
server.login('myemail@example.com', creds.token)
```

But I get: `Connection unexpectedly closed` and no e-mail was sent at all.

I am wondering how I could I make a login to SMTP server with OAuth2 connection and send an e-mail?